# mat-select required validation not working

Tags: angular5, angular2-forms, angular-material2, redux-form-validators

I have the following code

```
<form #createForm="ngForm">
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food"
      matInput
     [ngModel]
     food="food"
     #food="ngModel" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
<button [disabled]="!createForm.valid">submit</button>
```

Since I want the "selection" is a required field, the "submit" button should be disabled when the form is rendered. However, the "submit" button is enabled when the form is displayed. What is the problem?

Comment: Are you missing the name attribute to the mat-select? Like this is mandatory.. In my case this works..

`<form #myForm="ngForm"> <mat-select name="journal_bank_id" placeholder="Bank Account" [(ngModel)]="journal.journal_bank_id" required><mat-option>--</mat-option><mat-option *ngFor="let bank of bank_accounts | async" [value]="bank.bank_id">{{bank.bank_account_number }}</mat-option></mat-select><button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]='myForm.invalid'>Save</button>`

Comment: It should work more or less. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azgehl

Answer (score 15):

This works for me when I (a) use a `name` attribute and (b) use the two-way `ngModel` binding syntax.

i.e. Instead of this

`<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" matInput [ngModel] food="food" #food="ngModel" required>`

use this:

`<mat-select name="food" placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="food" required>`

Comment: two way binding does the trick, there's no need to use name attribute in order to make it work

Answer (score 5):

for validation in angular 5 use reactive forms. [refer this](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

*** componenet.ts *******

```
import { FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class Test implements OnInit{
foodform:FormGroup;
 constructor(){}

ngOnInit() {
// create form group of controls 
 this.foodform = new FormGroup({
   favoriteFood: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
 });
}
}
```

**** Component.html************

```
   <form #createForm="ngForm" [formGroup]="foodform ">
     <mat-form-field>
       <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food"
          matInput
         [ngModel]
         food="food"
         #food="ngModel"  formControlName="favoriteFood">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value" >
          {{ food.viewValue }}
        </mat-option>
       </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="foodform.controls['favoriteFood'].hasError('required') && foodform.controls['favoriteFood'].pristine">
                Required Message
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    </form>
```

use `[formGroup]` and `formControlName` in your html form.

Comment: I don't use reactive form and I am using template based component. Your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Correct this is not your answer when using template-driven forms.

Comment: This is the same as my question. The only thing differ from there is there is some more stuff in the component file.// create form group of controls 
 this.foodform = new FormGroup({
   favoriteFood: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
 });

Comment: It will add a * correctly, but it does not prevent "submit" enabled.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by writing a validation directive which checks if there is a value in the control and display an error if none. However, the directive doesn't add "*". I ended up using both "required" and my new validation directive.

Comment: This answer indirectly states that template driven forms are somehow depracated in Angular 5 which is not true. Does not fix original issue neither.

Answer (score 3):

The only way required field validation works on a `mat-select` is by using reactive form validation. Just import the respective components in typescript file:

```
import {FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
```

HTML file :

Remove your `ngModel` reference

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food"
      matInput [formControl]="foodControl"     
     required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This works for the required field validation. If you wanted to validate more probably you will end up accessing the `form` in the typescript file. Its weird that there is no option to do `form` validation, this is the only way i found to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at danger89's comment under your original question. 
You are missing the name attribute.
E.g:

```
<form #createForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitFunction(createForm)">
      <mat-form-field>
          <mat-select 
            placeholder="Favorite food"
            ngModel
            name="food"
            required
          >
            <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
              {{ food.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
      <button type="submit" [disabled]="!createForm.valid">submit</button>
  </form>
```

Because of the name attribute, your food.value can now be found at createForm.value.food when submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Import ReactiveFormsModule in you app module

`import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

and add its dependency in @NgModule decorator

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't get any solution to work using Ang8 + Material8 and a multi-select while using a FormGroup and a FormControl.  I ended up doing the following as a workaround.

First I added a tag to the mat-select, #thisselect

Then I tested the value of the tag for zero length in the submit button

```
<form [formGroup]="bypartForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="true">
                <mat-select #thisselect placeholder="Brands" formControlName="brands"
                    (selectionChange)="selectChanged($event)" multiple required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let brand of brandList" [value]="brand.name">{{brand.name}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field [hideRequiredMarker]="true">
                <input matInput autocomplete="off" placeholder="Part#" formControlName="part" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div class="form-buttons">
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!bypartForm.valid || (thisselect.value != undefined && thisselect.value.length == 0)">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem like you, and ReactiveForms is not a valid solution for me.
I solved it by adding `ngModel` AND `value` to the mat-input, in addition to what is mentioned above, the attribute `name` is very important, your code would end like this:

```
<form #createForm="ngForm">
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food"
      matInput
     [(ngModel)]="yourResult.foodId"
     [(value)]="yourResult.foodId"
     name="foodselect"
     required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.foodId">
      {{ food.viewValue }}
    </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   <mat-error 
   *ngIf="createForm.controls['foodselect'].hasError('required')">
   This is required
 </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</form>
<button [disabled]="!createForm.valid">submit</button>
```