# Angular : how to validate form with multi-select?

Tags: forms, validation, angular7

I am relatively new to Angular and I am trying to validate a huge form, with components such as mat-input and mat-labels. And at one point I had to use the `[formControl]` attribute in the HTML to use the multi-select from angular material as specified in the angular material documentation for version 7.

Now I already have a form with `[formControl]` attribute specified for the multi-select element. And this is inside a form that uses the `[formGroup]` attribute. Now to validate the form I believe that I have to use the `formControlName` attribute for the multi-select, just as we do for other elements, but the validation doesn't seem to happen.

Here is the HTML part of it:

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 300px;">
  <mat-select [formControl]="names" multiple>
    <mat-select-trigger>
      {{names.value ? names.value[0] : ''}}
      <span *ngIf="names.value?.length > 1" class="example-additional-selection">
        (+{{names.value.length - 1}} {{names.value?.length === 2 ? 'other' : 'others'}})
      </span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
    <mat-option (click)="selectAll(ev);" #ev >All</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let name of nameList" [disabled]="allSelected" [value]="name">{{name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is the component.ts part :

```
this.employeeHoursForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  baName: ['', [Validators.required]],
  category:['',[Validators.required]],
  list: ['',[Validators.required]],
  from: ['', [Validators.required]], 
  to: ['',[Validators.required]],
});
```

I tried using the `list` attribute as the `formControlName` value in the HTML but it didn't seem to work. Is it possible to validate with `[formControl]` and `formControlName=list` specified for the mat-select tag? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You need to use [formControl]="list" instead of [formControl]="names" if the mat select is for this `list` input field or else just create a new formControl names in the form builder

Comment: You mean I can also instead specify 'names' instead of the list in the form validators I guess, according to what you mentioned. But  that did not work too..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mat-select required validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545596/mat-select-required-validation-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I don't think so it helps because the op who posted it, doesn't appear to be using formControl attribute. but in my case, I am confused whether a formControl and formControlName attribute can be used together.

Comment: Check the answers with form control in that question

Comment: And using [formControl] is enough. Check the official document here https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-error-state-matcher

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But I will try to be more specific this time. I am referring to this link: https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-multiple where there is a formControl added to the select element and in the component. Now if I have to use this in a form, I have use a formControlName attribute to validate it. But using these two attributes together doesn't seem to work.